# Does this construction make sense?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, atomicinteger

Faced a project with this code:

```
   public class IndexUpdater implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
            FindIterable<Document> iterable = mongoService.getDocuments(entryMeta, null, "guid");
                iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(final Document document) {
                        count.incrementAndGet();
                        // A lot of code....
                        if (count.get() / 100 * 100 == count.get()) {
                            LOG.info(String.format("Processing: %s", count.get()));
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
   }
```

Here I am interested in three lines of code:

```
if (count.get() / 100 * 100 == count.get()) {
    LOG.info(String.format("Processing: %s", count.get()));
}
```

Does this condition make sense considering multithreading and the type of the AtomicInteger variable? Or is this a pointless check?
Interestingly, IntellijIdea does not emphasize this construct as meaningless.

Comment: I don't understand what  `count.get() / 100 * 100 == count.get()` is supposed to accomplish. Are you just trying to check if `count.get()%100==0`?

Comment: You won't always get the same value for `count.get()` on the two invocations. It would be easier to use `count.get() % 100 == 0`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense considering the practice of "writing code that does what you need": it rounds down to the nearest 100 and then prints if the rounded number is the original number, so... why not print when `count % 100 == 0`, which is the standard way to test for multiples-of?

Comment: *considering multithreading*: is there multithreading here? Does forEach really execute the Block on multiple threads?

Comment: "Interestingly, IntellijIdea does not emphasize this construct as meaningless" Intellij can't possibly determine how meaningful arbitrary code is. It will only flag "known" patterns as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call this code "meaningless", but rather *wrong* (or, it has probably-unintended semantics).

If this were being invoked in a multithreaded way, you wouldn't always get the same value for `count.get()` on the three invocations in the method (there are four if you include `count.incrementAndGet()`).

The consequences of this don't look catastrophic in *this* case - you'd perhaps miss a few logging statements, and you might see some unexpected messages like `Processing 101`, and then wonder why the number isn't a multiple of 100. But perhaps if you employed the same construct elsewhere, there would be more significant implications.

Put the result of `count.incrementAndGet()` into a variable (*), so you can use that afterwards.

But then, it would be easier to use `count.get() % 100 == 0` as well:

```
int value = count.incrementAndGet();
// A lot of code....
if (value % 100 == 0) {
  LOG.info(String.format("Processing: %s", value));
}
```

which is both correct (or, it is probably what is intended) and easier to read.

---

(*) Depending on what you actually want to show with this logging message, you might want to put the `count.incrementAndGet()` after "A lot of code".

Comment: There's still a race condition, since the OP would call incrementAndGet(), and then get(). The only call should be incrementAndGet().